# Sort blocks of columns according to specific column value in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame in `r`. Beginning at 2nd column, every 4 columns form a block. I need to sort these blocks as a whole based on the ordering of the 3, 7, 11, ..., element values. That is, move those 4-column blocks around so that their second column value is in an increasing order.

For example, if we have a data frame as following

```
0 7 2 3 4 1 2 2 3 4 2 1 8 3 9 1 7
4 9 1 2 1 8 1 0 4 5 1 3 2 1 3 2 7
...
```

I expect the result to be

```
0 1 2 2 3 3 9 1 7 4 2 1 8 7 2 3 4
4 1 3 2 7 5 1 3 2 8 1 0 4 9 1 2 1
...
```

Anybody can kindly help me?

Comment: I've added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each row you're ordering based on the first value in each 4-column block. This can be done with something like:

```
dat = rbind(c(0, 7, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 8, 3, 9, 1, 7),
            c(4, 9, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 0, 4, 5, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 7))
t(apply(dat, 1, function(x) {
  to.sort <- x[seq(2, ncol(dat), by=4)]
  x[c(1, rep(order(to.sort), each=4)*4 - c(2, 1, 0, -1))]
}))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
# [1,]    0    1    2    2    3    3    9    1    7     4     2     1     8
# [2,]    4    1    3    2    7    5    1    3    2     8     1     0     4
#      [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17]
# [1,]     7     2     3     4
# [2,]     9     1     2     1
```

The `apply` function is being called on each row of `dat`. First, we grab the first value of each 4-column block into a variable called `to.sort`. Then, we manipulate the output of the `order` function to construct the indexing for the row; `c(2, 1, 0, -1)` is recycled for each 4-column block and enables us to return all four columns in that block.

It's not too tough to generalize this to a function that does this operation for any number of columns to skip at the beginning `s` and any block size `b`:

```
order.blocks <- function(dat, s, b) {
  t(apply(dat, 1, function(x) {
    to.sort <- x[seq(s+1, ncol(dat), by=b)]
    if (s > 0) padding <- seq(s) else padding <- NULL
    x[c(padding, rep(order(to.sort), each=b)*b + seq(s+1-b, s))]
  }))
}
order.blocks(dat, 1, 2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
# [1,]    0    1    2    1    8    1    7    2    3     3     4     3     9
# [2,]    4    0    4    1    3    2    1    2    7     3     2     5     1
#      [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17]
# [1,]     4     2     7     2
# [2,]     8     1     9     1
```